# Images not showing in my view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Images are not showing on my `view`. When I do `var_dump($image)` it shows me valid result. When I load my view on browser images boxes appears but images not. I am using `codeigniter`.

Comment: Put your code as well

Comment: what is your path to them ?

Comment: edit your question with your comments please

Comment: edit you question and put your code there. code should not write in comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time, problem is sorted.

Comment: @Bakht check the answer post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

CI is **MVC**(**M**odel,**V**iew,**C**ontroller) format so always follow that as well.

**controller**

in your controller under main controller define

```
    public function  __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Product_area_model');

}
```

this should be your controller

```
    public function function_name()//define your funtion name
{
    $data['images'] = $this->Product_area_model->get_image();
    $data['data'] = $this->Product_area_model->product_list();
    $data['main_content'] ='admin/product_area/product_list';//don't know what you going to get. just insert cz of your purpose

    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}
```

In **Model**

```
   public function get_image()
{
   //code to retrieve image names 
    $dirname = "uploads/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*");
    return $images;
}
```

in **View**

```
<?php
foreach($images as $image)
{
    ?>
    <td><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $image ?>" height="100" width="100"></td>
<?php
}
?>
```